# ASP.NET how to pass Session variable in ListView

Tags: asp.net, session

I'm trying to pass a Session("sessionVar") on to ListView INSERT.  Is there any way I can achieve this. I tried this and dosns't seem to work:

```
InsertCommand="INSERT INTO [EmployeeTest] ([FName], [LName], [samAccount]) VALUES (@Fname, @LName,@samAccount)

<InsertParameters>
            <asp:Parameter Name="FName" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="LName" Type="String" />
            <asp:SessionParameter Name="EmployeeID" SessionField="samAccount" 
                Type="String" />
</InsertParameters>

On Page_Load:
Session["samAccount"]=getSamAccountFromActiveDirectory(UserName);
```

Am I missing anything? or Is it not possible to pass Session variable with in ListView.

Thank you.

Comment: its possible to pass parameter because asp.net have the seesion values as parameter

Comment: I pasted my answer have look to it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shouldn't you have EmployeeID as the db field name, not samAccount?

```
InsertCommand="INSERT INTO [EmployeeTest] ([FName], [LName], [EmployeeID]) VALUES (@Fname, @LName,@samAccount)
```

Answer (score 0):

I found problem with this

in insert command you need to pass the name of parameter rather than name of session field

like as below

```
InsertCommand="INSERT INTO [EmployeeTest] ([FName], [LName], 
[samAccount]) VALUES (@Fname, @LName,@EmployeeID)//changed from samAccount to EmployeeID
```